# T-SQL to search ID in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a mapping table below and I want to check either ID exists in the corresponding Table or not. For example: check ID 001 in "xxabc" database table and return "Yes" if table has 001 ID present else "No".

```
ID              TableName
--------------------------
001             xxabc
003             xxabc
004             xxpqr
009             xxghi
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT S.[ID]
      ,CASE WHEN M.[ID] IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
    --,IIF(M.[ID] IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') -- for SQL Server 2012+
FROM [source_table] S
LEFT JOIN [mapping_table] M
    ON S.[ID] = M.[ID]
```